# Filtering Multiple Data

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, first table is called 'submissions' and the second table is called 'area'

```
********  SUBMISSIONS TABLE  ********
userid  statusid  no      name    area    month    year    dateupdated
62      2         763     ABCD    Brazil      6    2013    2013-11-26 15:28
62      1         869     ABC     Brazil      7    2012    2013-11-26 15:10
62      2         869     ABC     Brazil      6    2013    2013-11-26 15:28
62      1         869     ABC     Brazil      6    2013    2013-11-26 14:50
61      1         763     ABCD    Brazil      6    2013    2013-11-26 14:50
54      1         200     ABCDE   US         12    2013    2013-11-26 21:02
32      2         200     ABCDE   US         12    2013    2013-11-26 21:03

******* AREA TABLE ********
  no      name    area     
  763     ABCD    Brazil  
  869     ABC     Brazil  
  869     ABC     Brazil  
  869     ABC     Brazil  
  763     ABCD    Brazil  
  200     ABCDE   US      
  200     ABCDE   US
```

I am trying to achieve the following: A user selects an Area, month and year via a dropdown (SELECT).  Once they have selected the 3 fields, the filtered data is displayed.

I want to the display the selection as per the fields that are filtering, but also display all other records in that particular area where is no data. Almost like an outstanding Report.. Example Below:

```
userid  statusid  no      name    area    month    year    dateupdated
62      2         763     ABCD    Brazil      6    2013    2013-11-26 15:28
62      1         869     ABC     Brazil      7    2012    2013-11-26 15:10
62      2         869     ABC     Brazil      6    2013    2013-11-26 15:28
62      1         869     ABC     Brazil      
61      1         763     ABCD    Brazil      
54      1         200     ABCDE   US        
32      2         200     ABCDE   US
```

Does anyone know how i can achieve this? Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like this

```
SELECT userid , statusid,  a.no  , a.name ,   a.area   , month ,   year ,   dateupdated 
FROM submission s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN area a 
ON s.no = a.no 
WHERE month = 12 AND 
year = 2013 AND
a.area = 'US'
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a869/6)

Comment: Thanks for that.. but it doesn't seem to work.. If i select the fields to filter on, it does not show the other names in that selected area. I need to see which names are still outstanding per the 3 selects (month, year and area). If i select June 2013 and the US, i want to see the records which have data for that period and all other 'names' with no data (month, year and dateupdated) would be blank